# Select statement with case condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display my data using case condition. 
Right now in my database:

```
Id     MoodHappy   MoodSad
1          1          0
```

I want to retrieve this value but I don’t want to show as 1 or 0. 
I would like to display if id 1 is selected and moodhappy is equal to 1 then display happy.

```
"Select moodHappy, case when moodHappy = 1 then 'Happy' end as moodlvl from Mood"; 

SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
addScholarship userObj = new addScholarship();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    string moody = myReader["moodHappy"].ToString();
    userObj = new addScholarship(moody);
}
myReader.Close();
return userObj;
```

the result still display 1 and not happy

Comment: Where do you display anything? Is see you read a reader. You create objects, and that is it.

Comment: If you don´t want to return the `MoodHappy`-value but `"Happy"` instead simply omit the `moodHappy` from your selection and use only the `case when`-statement? `Select case when moodHappy = 1 then 'Happy' end as moodlvl from Mood`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select moodHappy, case when moodHappy = 1 then 'Happy' else 'Sad' end as moodlvl from Mood

SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
addScholarship userObj = new addScholarship();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    string moody = myReader["moodlvl "].ToString();
    userObj = new addScholarship(moody);
}
myReader.Close();
return userObj;
```